# Invalid Column Index

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

Below is part of my code. I keep getting errors for my database part. I've looked them up multiple places and can't seem to find an answer. Any suggestions? The code and what's printed as errors are shown below!

```
public void deleteEmployee()
{
    String sqlQuery;
    sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.EMPLOYEE";
    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    sendDBCommand(sqlQuery);    
}

public void deleteAccident()
{
    String sqlQuery;
    sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.ACCIDENT";
    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    sendDBCommand(sqlQuery);
} 

public void deleteTruck()
{
    String sqlQuery;
    sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.TRUCK";
    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    sendDBCommand(sqlQuery);
}

public void deleteHomeState()
{
    String sqlQuery;
    sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.HOMESTATE";
    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    sendDBCommand(sqlQuery);
}

public void deleteCountry()
{
    String sqlQuery;
    sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.COUNTRY";
    System.out.println(sqlQuery);
    sendDBCommand(sqlQuery);
}
```

Here are the errors that keep popping up:

```
run:
DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.HOMESTATE
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.COUNTRY
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.TRUCK
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.ACCIDENT
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.EMPLOYEE
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence
```

Also, I call all the delete methods in order when my program presses the "Insert button"

How can I get rid of these error messages?

Here's my sendDBCommand:

```
public static void sendDBCommand(String sqlQuery)
{
    String jdbcConnectionURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    String userID = "javauser";
    String userPASS = "javapass";

    try
    {
        Connection conn = getDBConnection(jdbcConnectionURL, userID, userPASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

        int traverse = 0;
        while (rset.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rset.getString(1) + " " + rset.getString(2));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, we don't know what "sendDBCommand" does exactly, so who knows?  Why do you list all these different databases?

Comment: I just added the sendDBCommand! For our program we have to empty all the tables every time we press the "insert button" then repopulate them. HOMESTATE, COUNTRY and TRUCK are prepopulated

Comment: You need to show us also `sendDBCommand(sqlQuery);` code, since the exception is thrown somwhere in this method.

Comment: `DELETE FROM JAVAUSER.ACCIDENT` command doesn't return any resutset, but you are trying to get results from this command in `sendDBCommand(,,,)` method using `rset.getString(1)`

Comment: so how can I fix that? I kind of understand what you're saying but I'm not fully on board.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a counter and print the result, so maybe you should have a clue, and as well, with delete there is no resultset it should be executeUpdate instead.